# Coldfusion: update table based on form selection

Tags: list, coldfusion, insert, sql-update, coldfusion-10

I have a form which allows users to assign multiple records to a technician by Area number. It does this by outputting a line for each area in the outstanding records with a select list of the joined technician:

```
<cfoutput query="getAreaList">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="hub">DWS Area:</label>
        <input type="text" name="oparea" id="oparea" value="#OpArea#" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sub">Assign to:</label>
        <select id="series" name="sub" class="form-control">
            <cfloop query="getTechAreas">
            <cfif OpArea EQ getAreaList.OpArea>
            <option value="#username#" class="#OpArea#">#Displayname#</option>
            </cfif>
            </cfloop>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        </cfoutput>
```

The resultant output looks like this - two lists of data:

> form.opArea: Area 4,Area 5
> form.sub: PERSON1,PERSON2

My aim is to update my jobs table, where each row for the specific `form.OpArea` is updated with the name of the technician, `form.sub`.

How do I loop through each list and insert the correct tech name where the `opArea` is matched?

I have tried looping through the insert but the whole of the list is being inserted, not the currently evaluated list item. I'm currently just trying to insert this into a holding table to test my code:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop list="#form.oparea#" index="i">
<cfquery datasource="cfLKDM" name="insertdata">
    insert into [DWS_General_Dev].[LogSure].[Holding]
    (AreaNo)
    values
    ('#form.oparea#')
</cfquery>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the whole list because you are still referencing the form field `form.oparea` within your loop. Which contains the entire list. When looping over a list, as you are doing, the `cfloop` will populate the `index` variable with the current value of the list item during each iteration.

So instead of using `form.oparea` you should be using `i` in your example. You should change the name of that index variable to be more descriptive.

Like this for your example:

```
<cfloop list="#form.oparea#" index="i">
    <cfquery datasource="cfLKDM" name="insertdata">
        insert into [DWS_General_Dev].[LogSure].[Holding]
        (AreaNo)
        values
        ('#i#')
    </cfquery>
```

Better yet change the index variable name to be more descriptive:

```
<cfloop list="#form.oparea#" index="thisOPArea">
    <cfquery datasource="cfLKDM" name="insertdata">
        insert into [DWS_General_Dev].[LogSure].[Holding]
        (AreaNo)
        values
        ('#thisOPArea#')
    </cfquery>
```

Comment: Another option is to skip the loop and insert the values directly from the source tables, fltering with `<cfqueryparam list=true ....>`. Also, use numeric id's, instead of string names, if possible - to avoid delimiter issues.